# Htaccess pagination and multiple query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination, query-string

I'm trying to setup a redirect in order to showcase a business page, with the listings on that page, paginated.

This is how I want the URL to look like:

```
https://www.propertypost.lk/company/colomborent/1
```

Where the last number in the URL, is the page number.

I've been able to get this to work: https://www.propertypost.lk/company/colomborent

But I can't seem to figure out how to include the pagination part (which shouldn't be mandatory).

This is how the URL looks without htaccess:

```
https://www.propertypost.lk/agent-business-page.php?url=colomborent&page=1
```

And here is my htaccess rewrite rule that works:

```
RewriteRule     ^company/([^\s]+[\w])/?$    agent-business-page.php?url=$1
```

And this is what I tried which does not work...:

```
RewriteRule     ^company/([^\s]+[\w])/([^\s]+[\w])/?$   agent-business-page.php?url=$1&page=$2
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You want `\d` instead of `\w` to capture the numerical pagination number argument.

Comment: And what is that strange `[^\s+]` for?

Comment: @arkascha I don't know I'm afraid. This is what I came up with while Googling for a solution to URL rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want \d instead of \w to capture the numerical pagination number argument. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?company/(\w+)/?$ /agent-business-page.php?url=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?company/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ /agent-business-page.php?url=$1&page=$2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you @arkascha! I've been on this for quite a few days now, trying to figure out how to sort out the htaccess. Your answer worked fantastic. 

On another note, so htaccess can slow down the http server. I definitely don't want that happening.Thanks for the tip on server host configurations, I'll probably need that extra ounce of speed to cater better to traffic. I've added your suggestion to the to-do list, but don't have a clue yet how to do it. Do feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: In a nutshell: if you operate the http server yourself, if you have control over the http server's host configuration, then you do _not_ want to use dynamic configuration files for this but instead configure the rule set inside the virtual host configuration. Then you can even disable the consideration of dynamic configuration files completely.